# What's the difference between GraphQL and rest api

Tags: json, rest, http, graphql

I want to know what are all reasons of **qraphQL** to be used instead of **rest api**.

As much I know instead of making multiple requests (to reduce HTTP request), can make a group of HTTP requests in one request using **graphQL**.

Can anybody describe little more, please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Multiple blogs are on internet for this. Please refer and one of them is https://blog.apollographql.com/graphql-vs-rest-5d425123e34b?gi=b799539d92a0

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are many articles covering this question in more details available on the internet. I am trying to give a short overview here.

GraphQL offers a couple of advantages over REST.

**Main difference**

In a *REST* interface, everything is about resources. For example, you'd get the resources "car" with ID 25 and ID 83 by calling an endpoint like this:

```
GET /cars/25
GET /cars/83
```

Note, how you have to call the interface twice. The endpoint ("cars") and your resource are coupled.

In *GraphQL* you could get both cars with one call, using this example query:

```
GET /api?query={ car(ids: [25, 83]) { model, manufacturer { address } } }
```

Note, how you even specified the exact data you want to fetch (model, manufacturer and its address). Compared to REST, the endpoint ("api") is not resource-specific anymore.

**Some advantages**

- As already mentioned in the question, you can reduce the amount of HTTP operations with the help of GraphQL queries (avoid underfetching).
- By specifying exactly, which data you want to fetch, you are able to reduce the overhead being transmitted over the interface (avoid overfetching).
- By using flexible queries with GraphQL, you're more likely to avoid coupling the interface consumer too tight to the producer by not implementing exactly the requirements of a specific consumer into a REST interface with defined endpoints.
- Because each consumer exactly specifies which data is required with GraphQL, you can gather more detailed statistics on data usage in your backend.