# What is major difference between Graph API and REST API?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest

I was working on a summer project and I wanted to know which one should a backend developer focus on building a graph api or a rest api? And what are their use cases.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between GraphQL and rest api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60200177/whats-the-difference-between-graphql-and-rest-api)

Answer (score 0):

Graph API's use GraphQL or some similar language, which is basically a query language. In other words, it's a language designed to make requests to a server. It's a skill you have to learn, and something I haven't personally studied.

Rest API's on the other hand use end points and 'keywords' to make requests. For example, I could make a 'GET' request to www.somewebsite.com/api/users and the server would have a predefined function to run based on that request. They can use 'GET', 'PUT', 'DELETE', and a variety of other keywords, and the end points are completely defined by the creator of the server.

TLDR: Graph Api's use a specific query language to make the requests while REST Api's use keywords and endpoints to make requests. Rest api's are easier to learn and more simple, while some may argue that Graph API's are more powerful.